# Can I do this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I have the following 2 lines of code

```
errors.add_to_base I18n.t :error_message if value != 1
return false if !errors.blank?
```

Is it possible to condense this into 1 line of code? I need to do this in multiple places with different error message and condition. Also, "return false" is to stop the flow of an ActiveRecord lifecycle.

Comment: Due to side-effects I would not try to condense that. It will only make the code *less readable*. It is possible by using some of the operations which can "join statements" (e.g. coalesce them into expressions (`&&` and `||` and `,` can be used in tricky ways) or use `;` to put multiple statements on a line). I would actual argue for *leading* conditional syntax.

Comment: Yeah that crossed my mind but I do use this chunk of code in several places and would like to either put them in a method or condense it into 1 line.

Comment: Use a method? More readable and shorter? Win \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. If you know `errors.blank?` will be true unless the first condition fires then:

```
(errors.add_to_base I18n.t :error_message; return) if value != 1
```

***Update:*** Aha, you are willing to define a method. How about a `Proc` object? It's better than a method here in that if the `Proc` block returns then the invocation will return from the surrounding method.

```
test = Proc.new do |cond, msg|
  errors.add_to_base I18n.t msg if cond
  return unless errors.blank?
end
# ...
test.call value != 1, :error_message
```

---

<sup>Note that you don't need to `return false` as a plain `return` will return `nil` and that will be good enough unless some sadist is doing something like `f().class == NilClass`. :-)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that is a bit better though I'm wondering if there is a way to turn this into a method with errors, error_message, condition as params.

Comment: Proc is a good idea, can I put this in a module? Reason being is that I need to call it from multiple models.

Comment: Sure, in fact, I imagine you could make it a constant.

Comment: Cool, I tried with a global constant, it works except that it doesn't stop the ActiveRecord lifecycle but it's a cool trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of how the boolean logic operators work and do something like this:

```
value != 1 && errors.add_to_base I18n.t :error_message && return false
```

Not very clear, I wouldn't recommend using it. Also if `errors.add_to_base` returns something that's "falseish" the return false wouldn't happen.

Remember: "Always code as if the person who will maintain your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live”

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though as you said, it's hard to read and I certainly don't want a violent psychopath on my case ;)